# How to combine an array that has the same associative key values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, associative-array

I am trying to create an array from looping through posts in wordpress and building an array of people, the games they've played and the scores that they have posted per game.

My current code:

```
    $world_rank = [];
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
          $category = get_the_category();
          $cat_name = $category[0]->cat_name;
          $score = get_field('score');
          $author = get_the_author();

          $array_size = sizeof($world_rank[$author]['games']);
          if( $array_size < 1 ){
            $world_rank[$author]['games'][] = ['name' =>  addslashes($cat_name), 'scores' => [$score] ];
          }else{
            // loop through the array and see if they have been similar game names if so, add them to push array
            $i = 0;
            foreach($world_rank[$author]['games'] as $game){
              if($game['name'] == $cat_name){
                echo 'Same name ' .$game['scores']. ' score is '.$score.'</br>';
                array_push($game['scores'], $score);
// this doesn't seem to work
                // break;
              }
              else if($game['name'] !== $cat_name && $i == $array_size - 1 ){ //
                // if the names are not the same create a new array for the other game
                $world_rank[$author]['games'][] = ['name' =>  addslashes($cat_name), 'scores' => [$score] ];
              }
              $i++;
            }
          }
        endwhile;
```

The above output gives this:

```
$world_rank = array (
      'frantheman' => 
      array (
        'games' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'Candy',
            'scores' => 
            array (
              0 => '23',
            ),
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'PopCorn',
            'scores' => 
            array (
              0 => '25',
            ),
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'Chocolate',
            'scores' => 
            array (
              0 => '5',
            ),
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'Candy',
            'scores' => 
            array (
              0 => '25',
            ),
          ),
        )
      );
```

How can I make it so that the world_rank array has the 'Candy' value as 1 array since the 'Candy' value appears twice in the array, and combine the scores of the 'Candy' key. So to make it now look like:

```
$world_rank = array (
  'frantheman' => 
  array (
    'games' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Candy',
        'scores' => 
        array (
          0 => '23',
          1 => '25' 
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'PopCorn',
        'scores' => 
        array (
          0 => '25',
        ),
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Chocolate',
        'scores' => 
        array (
          0 => '5',
        ),
      )
  );
```

As you can see, in the new array, the 'Candy' has 2 arrays for the scores. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide the code how do you create that 1st array

Comment: @Tarasovych its been updated. Thanks for the comment asking me to put it in, and not a down vote unlike others have.

Comment: You have to put all game's scores into exist array with `array_push()`, using `foreach()`

Comment: Thanks, but thats what I did.Right here: f($game['name'] == $cat_name){
                echo 'Same name ' .$game['scores']. ' score is '.$score.'</br>';
                array_push($game['scores'], $score);
// this doesn't seem to work
                // break;
              }

Comment: If i do an echo within that condition, I see its adding to the array at the 'Candy' name key. However, when I print the final result of the array, I get the 1st output that I showed in my question.

Comment: Are you sure you `print()` what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**  After much back and forth with the OP, I have rewritten my answer and the OP's original script.

This is the testable script: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1109764564bdd5286c5342f07c2f78949d28e830))

```
$raw_input=[
    ['frantheman','Candy Crush','11'],
    ['frantheman','Candy Crush','5'],
    ['frantheman','Candy Crush','4'],
    ['frantheman','Candy Crush','23'],
    ['frantheman','Candy Crush','25'],
    ['frantheman','Candy Crush',NULL],
    ['frantheman','Blackjack','68'],
    ['frantheman','Blackjack',NULL],
    ['frantheman','Blackjack','90'],
    ['frantheman','Killer Instinct','25'],
    ['frantheman','Grand Theft Auto V','5'],
    ['frantheman','Counter-Strike: Global Offensive','67'],
    ['frantheman','Lawbreakers','456'],
    ['Braconda','Overwatch','24459'],
    ['Braconda','Overwatch','70'],
    ['ScotGamer1','Overwatch','24359'],
    ['ScotGamer1','Blackjack','21'],
    ['ScotGamer1','Grand Theft Auto V','23386'],
    ['ScotGamer1','Dota 2','2560'],
    ['John','Counter-Strike: Global Offensive','75656'],
    ['John','Counter-Strike: Global Offensive','19000'],
    ['John','Team Fortress 2','8686'],
    ['John','Team Fortress 2','7755'],
    ['John','Dota 2','86766'],
    ['John','Dota 2','12345'],
    ['John','Candy Crush','9999999999999999'],
    ['John','Candy Crush','66'],
    ['John','PLAYERUNKNOWN’S BATTLEGROUNDS','42'],
    ['John','Lawbreakers','5345345'],
    ['John','Lawbreakers','54321']
];

$user_game_stats=[];  // this will be the final output array containing all statistics
foreach($raw_input as $a){
    $game = addslashes($a[1]);
    $user = $a[0];
    $score=intval($a[2]);

    $user_game_stats[$user][$game]['scores'][]=$score;
    if(!isset($user_game_stats[$user][$game]['high_score']) || $score>$user_game_stats[$user][$game]['high_score']){
        $user_game_stats[$user][$game]['high_score']=$score;
        $user_high_scores_by_game[$game][$user]=$score;  // this is a temporary array for calculating rank
    }
}

// a second loop is essential because the rank calculations involve the users' high scores and player count per game
foreach($user_high_scores_by_game as $game=>$user_scores){
    $total_game_users=count($user_scores);
    arsort($user_scores);  // sort the users by their high score in DESC order and preserve the keys (usernames)
    $ordered_users=array_keys($user_scores);  // high scores are no longer required, we just want to determine rank
    foreach($ordered_users as $number=>$user){
        $user_game_stats[$user][$game]['rank']=++$number;  // starts from zero so $number is modified/increased by one for human-friendly rank
        $user_game_stats[$user][$game]['efficiency']=$number / ($total_game_users * .1); // I don't like "efficiency" but can't offer a better term
        // you may want to introduce rounding on the efficiency calculation
    }
}
var_export($user_game_stats);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'frantheman' => 
  array (
    'Candy Crush' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 11,
        1 => 5,
        2 => 4,
        3 => 23,
        4 => 25,
        5 => 0,
      ),
      'high_score' => 25,
      'rank' => 2,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
    'Blackjack' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 68,
        1 => 0,
        2 => 90,
      ),
      'high_score' => 90,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 5.0,
    ),
    'Killer Instinct' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 25,
      ),
      'high_score' => 25,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
    'Grand Theft Auto V' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 5,
      ),
      'high_score' => 5,
      'rank' => 2,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
    'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 67,
      ),
      'high_score' => 67,
      'rank' => 2,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
    'Lawbreakers' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 456,
      ),
      'high_score' => 456,
      'rank' => 2,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
  ),
  'Braconda' => 
  array (
    'Overwatch' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 24459,
        1 => 70,
      ),
      'high_score' => 24459,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 5.0,
    ),
  ),
  'ScotGamer1' => 
  array (
    'Overwatch' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 24359,
      ),
      'high_score' => 24359,
      'rank' => 2,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
    'Blackjack' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 21,
      ),
      'high_score' => 21,
      'rank' => 2,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
    'Grand Theft Auto V' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 23386,
      ),
      'high_score' => 23386,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 5.0,
    ),
    'Dota 2' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 2560,
      ),
      'high_score' => 2560,
      'rank' => 2,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
  ),
  'John' => 
  array (
    'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 75656,
        1 => 19000,
      ),
      'high_score' => 75656,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 5.0,
    ),
    'Team Fortress 2' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 8686,
        1 => 7755,
      ),
      'high_score' => 8686,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
    'Dota 2' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 86766,
        1 => 12345,
      ),
      'high_score' => 86766,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 5.0,
    ),
    'Candy Crush' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 9999999999999999,
        1 => 66,
      ),
      'high_score' => 9999999999999999,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 5.0,
    ),
    'PLAYERUNKNOWN’S BATTLEGROUNDS' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 42,
      ),
      'high_score' => 42,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 10.0,
    ),
    'Lawbreakers' => 
    array (
      'scores' => 
      array (
        0 => 5345345,
        1 => 54321,
      ),
      'high_score' => 5345345,
      'rank' => 1,
      'efficiency' => 5.0,
    ),
  ),
)
```

This is the WP implementation of my snippet:

```
$user_game_stats=[];  // this will be the final output array containing all statistics
while($the_query->have_posts()){
    $the_query->the_post();
    $game = addslashes(get_the_category()[0]->cat_name);
    $user = get_the_author();
    $score=intval(get_field('score'));

    $user_game_stats[$user][$game]['scores'][]=$score;
    if(!isset($user_game_stats[$user][$game]['high_score']) || $score>$user_game_stats[$user][$game]['high_score']){
        $user_game_stats[$user][$game]['high_score']=$score;
        $user_high_scores_by_game[$game][$user]=$score;  // this is a temporary array for calculating rank
    }
}

// a second loop is essential because the rank calculations involve the users' high scores and player count per game
foreach($user_high_scores_by_game as $game=>$user_scores){
    $total_game_users=count($user_scores);
    arsort($user_scores);  // sort the users by their high score in DESC order and preserve the keys (usernames)
    $ordered_users=array_keys($user_scores);  // high scores are no longer required, we just want to determine rank
    foreach($ordered_users as $number=>$user){
        $user_game_stats[$user][$game]['rank']=++$number;  // starts from zero so $number is modified/increased by one for human-friendly rank
        $user_game_stats[$user][$game]['efficiency']=$number / ($total_game_users * .1); // I don't like "efficiency" but can't offer a better term
        // you may want to introduce rounding on the efficiency calculation
    }
}
var_export($user_game_stats);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a small mistake in your code. If you want to modify $game inside the foreach you need to traverse it by reference. Just make your foreach:

```
foreach($world_rank[$author]['games'] as &$game){
```

Then you actually modify the actual scores array and don't create a local copy. (Google PHP copy on write, if you want to read more about it).

You also need the break statement, because otherwise you create another element in your end of loop condition. But you already put it in the right place; un-comment it.

**Alternative**

**What I added below alternative was wrong!** deleted.